# Travis-CI: "sudo: must be setuid root"

Tags: php, laravel, travis-ci

I am new to Travis-CI and I am trying to set up a Laravel PHP project on that. When I ran the first command with `sudo`, I always get something like the following:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-caad8021.prod.travis-ci.com:travis-linux-11


Installing an SSH key from: default repository key
Key fingerprint: a8:40:9f:12:b2:b1:b0:a9:55:9e:e1:e7:9e:e7:6f:52

1.07s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=view git@github.com:user/repo.git user/repo
$ cd user/repo
$ git checkout -qf 014a2be255b475550e7c52f6e04d70f84d82f3e2
stop: Unknown instance: 

Sudo, the FireFox addon, setuid and setgid have been disabled.


Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export DB=mysql

0.03s$ phpenv global 5.4
0.09s$ php --version
PHP 5.4.33 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2014 15:57:23) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
0.12s$ composer --version
Composer version 31eadc6920cd1866bc061fb0087798c37e2b7d14 2014-09-25 17:49:51
0.01s$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: must be setuid root

The command "sudo apt-get update" failed and exited with 1 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

Comment: Are you using the educational version with private repos?

Comment: @JordiKroon exactly as you say. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer in another topic on Stack Overflow. It is because of security reasons and will be fixed soon.

---

> Builds running on our **Docker based architecture currently cannot be allowed sudo access** due to certain security concerns in the LXC/Docker layer. We hope this will be fixed in the near future, but unfortunately the issue is out of our own hands.

For more information click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299552/travis-sudo-is-disabled).