# Failed to build python project on Travis CI

Tags: python, travis-ci

I've pyhash installed already, why does it always say that it can't find the module? Can anyone help me?

here is my .travis.yml:

```
language: python
before_install:
    - sudo apt-get -qq update
    - sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
python:
    - "2.7"
install:
    - sudo pip install pyhash
script: py.test
```

And this is my project directory:

```
/bloom
    __init__.py
    /src
       __init__.py
       f1.py
       f2.py
    /test
       __init__.py
       test_f1.py
       test_f2.py
```

The error message is:

> ImportError: No module named pyhash

But I've seen it installed in the cmd window.

Comment: Please show the error. And I think you don't need sudo with pip — just `pip install` is enough.

Comment: How are you using `sudo`' within Travis if you did not enable it?

Comment: i've tried add sudo enable, it still doesn't work

Comment: Try `sudo: required` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26299552/1009132)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Try getting rid of all `sudo` calls, use addon:apt to install boost requirements and `pip install --user pyhash` (however that didn't help with python3.5).

I did several tests and it looks like if you use `sudo pip install` for installing package it then is not visible by your install script user. See [this travis build](https://travis-ci.org/runningt/TrainingEnhancer/builds/242873883) for example. 
In my tests it did't matter if `sudo: required` was added to `.travis.yml` or not.

Unfortunatelly  [without sudo](https://travis-ci.org/runningt/TrainingEnhancer/builds/242865581) it is impossible to `pip install pyhash`, because of `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/libboost_python.so'` error.

However I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036259/how-to-write-travis-yml-if-my-project-deps-on-python-and-nodejs) question on stackoverflow and it looks like you can use `pip install --user` instead of `sudo pip install`.

I also [tested](https://travis-ci.org/runningt/TrainingEnhancer/builds/242881395) this approach and unfortunatelly you can't use `--user` in my configuration. Error was: `Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

So finally I tried to use [apt addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon) instead of `sudo apt-get install` to make sure `sudo:required` is not used but it also [did not help](https://travis-ci.org/runningt/TrainingEnhancer/builds/242887366).

Maybe you would have more luck with python2.7, if no try creating issue for [travis-ci](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues)